# How to add custom editable field to an attendee entry in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I need to have the Attendee sublist inside the Event record to store the "Ministry" of each attendee. An Attendee can have a different group in every event so placing the "Ministry" inside the Attendee record will not work.

I have tried the following steps
Fields > Attendees > New Field. but it adds the Ministry field at the Attendees subtab and not per entry.

[The encricled field should be in the red lines per entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gxMt.png)

thanks in advance!